Phone crashes on launch flutter app after running on debug mode
I used the package flutter_launcher_icons from pub.dev to generate icons for my flutter app using my custom app logo. I then built the app but it keeps crashing the device when it launches.
i also saw an error log on console
E/AndroidRuntime(10181): FATAL EXCEPTION: wmshell.splashworker
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.draw(android.graphics.Canvas)' on a null object reference

Atached is a picture of the app installed on the device clearly showing that something went wrong during the icon generating process. I think it could be because i mistakenly use a .jpg file instead of the recommended .png file. Ive been unable to reverse this since then.
i tried flutter clean then building afresh but it doesnt solve the issue.
Any help would be appreciated.
